# Beautiful Soup Find, Find_all

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

My sample code:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from requests import get
>>> url = 'https://nationaldaycalendar.com/what-is-national-today/'
>>> response = get(url)
>>> html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
>>> national_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'eventon_events_list')
>>> container = national_container.find_all(itemprop='description').get('content')
This line ^ Resulted in an error
```

The error thrown :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    container = national_container.find_all(itemprop='description').get('content')
  File "C:\Users\hyuiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2160, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get the required content:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url = 'https://nationaldaycalendar.com/what-is-national-today/'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
national_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'eventon_events_list')
container = national_container[0].find('meta', {'itemprop':'description'}).get('content')
print(container)
```

Prints the output as:

```
NATIONAL CHOCOLATE MILKSHAKE DAY
```